# Getting the current post number / make posts increment

Tags: wp-query, count

I'm creating a site similar to http://thegreatdiscontent.com/ in that there's a bunch of posts on the site, and only one post gets shown per page.

I want to add a counter that says something like: "Issue #210" at the top of each post, as they have done with http://alistapart.com/. This would increment with each new post.

I've seen it out there to use `wp_query->current_post`, but that only works when you run through a loop. I'm only showing one post per page, so `wp_query` always returns 0.

Any ideas how I can make my posts increment?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one persistent numerical thing about post is ID, however it is sequential for *all* posts, so you will have gaps if using it.

It would be easiest to assign a number and store it in custom field on post creation. Probably take it from an option and increment it there, so that your numbering doesn't shift if you delete a post and such.

Comment: Good call. In the time it would take me to add this custom field every week or two, it would be no big deal. Good advice.